# How can I define a delegate function in the function call?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a delegate function that does a callback. 
What I want to do is the following:

```
delegate void someDelegate( int i );
callFunction( int i, someDelate del )
{
    del.invoke( i );
}
callFunction( 10, void( int i )
{ 
    printf( i ); 
} );
```

I know this is possible but I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do from the pseudo-code you've provided. Please provide a short but *complete* example. What do you expect `void( int i )` to mean, for example? Are you actually just looking for lambda expressions? `callFunction(10, i => Console.WriteLine(i))`?

Comment: What I want to do is create a definition for the function so that I don't have to leave the function body itself, so that I have still have the variables defined in the calling function. For example when using threading and when I get a callback that the thread has finished executing, I want to handle that callback in the original function that created the thread. Otherwise, I lost the data that I was working with

Comment: I thought that was something like 
callFunction( 10, new someDelegate( int i )
{
    printf( i );
} );

Comment: Well there's `delegate(int i) { ...}` for anonymous methods... but those are very rarely useful now.

Comment: And yes, having access to local variables is precisely what lambda expressions allow. It's really unclear to me why you think Jenish's answer doesn't work for you. You should really try to clarify your question (don't just add comments).

Comment: you're right, it works :)
have accepted his answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is lambda syntax like this what are you looking for?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        callFunction(10, (i) =>
        {
            //printf( i ); 
        });
    }

    public delegate void someDelegate(int i);
    public static void callFunction(int i, someDelegate del)
    {
        del.Invoke(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not precisely, at least, what I want to do is to handle the callback in the original call. So, in this example, suppose I have done some calculations in main, then create another thread to perform some other calculations, I want the same function (static void Main) to handle the execution finished callback from the thread, so my previous calculations are in the same scope. 
See, I don't call the actual function, I just know what the signature is of the callback.